# Adding Applications to Gnome DO

Tags: linux, gnome-do

I have recently started using Chromium rather than Firefox on my laptop, primarily due to poor performance with Firefox. I always launched my browser via Gnome DO (Win+Space, Firefox, enter). I would like to do the same for Chromium but can't find any documentaiton in regards to adding aliases to Gnome DO.

Any ideas on how I can add Chromium to Gnome DO? I don't need any advanced functionality, just want to Win+Space, Chrome (or Chromium), enter.

Comment: btw. The "Win" key as you describe it, is actually called the Super Key. And your description is kinda... offensive...

Comment: How is his description offensive?

Comment: @aviraldg Yes, I understand DO calls it the super key, regardless of it's name it has a Windows logo emblazoned across it. How is my description offensive? Referring to FF's horrible Linux performance? That's not offensive, it's fact...

Comment: BTW: Thanks for the belongs-on-superuser tag... I completely agree. I keep forgetting we have more options than StackOverflow now.

Comment: Just a note: It's not Gnome DO that calls it super, it's Linux, while the key might have a Windows logo on your keyboard, there is no Win key on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Gnome DO automatically searches the contents of your Gnome applications menu. If the app is listed in there, you should be able to search for it from Gnome Do.

Comment: Any idea on how often this search happens or how to force DO to search? I'm on Linux Mint Felicia, Chromium has been installed from Launchpad's PPA via apt-get for 2 hours. Still no results via DO.

Comment: I think it re-indexes every time the app starts. If you haven't already, try quitting and restarting Gnome Do.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to igul222's answer, if you type in the entire name of the executable, it will present you with the option to 'run' it, even if it isn't in your menu. The downside is you do have to type the entire name.

Answer (score 0):

Add the application to the Gnome Menu, then restart Gnome-Do. You may use Gnome-Do to call up and edit the "Main Menu"

Answer (score 0):

remove from ~/.local/share/applications, re-add to Gnome menu, then re-start gnome-do.

[Remove an entry from Gnome-Do memory](https://answers.launchpad.net/do/+question/62643)